# Insert in binary tree using recursion

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree

I am trying to implement binary tree NOT binary search tree. I spent a good amount of time to write insert operation using recursion but did not get.

It should be a complete tree that is filling from left to right.

Can someone help me with that?Preferably in Java.

The following is the iterative way to do it .(:( this is not even working))

```
  public static void insertNode(Node root,int x){

        if(root==null) {

            root = new Node(x);
            return;
        }

        Node current;
        Queue<Node> qq = new LinkedList<Node>();

        ((LinkedList<Node>) qq).push(root);

        while(true){
            current=qq.peek();
            if(current.leftchild==null){
                Node child = new Node(x);
                child.parent = current;
                current.leftchild=child;

                return;
            }
            else { ((LinkedList<Node>) qq).push(current.leftchild);}
            if(current.rightChild==null){

                Node child = new Node(x);
                child.parent=current;
                current.rightChild=child;
                return;
            }
            else{
                ((LinkedList<Node>) qq).push(current.rightChild);
            }

            ((LinkedList<Node>) qq).pop();


        }
```

Comment: Hello Welcome to StackOverflow, This question does not provide enough information always try to provide some information related to what you tried so far with some of your code and where did you stuck. Help people to help you. also have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: its a basic question ,how to do the insert operation . I believe that question is clear .Is not it ?

Comment: as stated in my comment, please share what did you try so far and what didn't work? You always need to provide a minimal example of what didn't work.

Comment: @ZeeshanAdil... I did as you suggested .

Comment: what's the point of recursion? if you insert into binary tree, simply make the new node a tree root

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are pushing into the Linked List when actually you want to add to the list. 
`LinkedList.push(element)` adds `element` to the front of the list while the `LinkedList.add(element)` will add `element` to the end. Following is the correct snippet:

```
  public static void insertNode(Node root,int x){
  {
      if(root==null) {
          root = new Node(x);
          return;
      }

      Node current;
      Queue<Node> qq = new LinkedList<Node>();

      ((LinkedList<Node>) qq).push(root);

      while(true){
          current=qq.peek();
          if(current.leftchild==null){
              Node child = new Node(x);
              child.parent = current;
              current.leftchild=child;
              return;
           }
           else {
              ((LinkedList<Node>) qq).add(current.leftchild);}
           if(current.rightChild==null){

               Node child = new Node(x);
               child.parent=current;
               current.rightChild=child;
               return;
            }
            else{
                ((LinkedList<Node>) qq).add(current.rightChild);
            }

            ((LinkedList<Node>) qq).pop();
         }
    }
```